# NLog doesn't delete old log files

Tags: .net, windows-services, nlog

I have this config for NLog in my Windows service. The requirements are 1 file per day and keep maximum 10 files.

```
  <variable name="logPath" value="D:\infra\project\logs"/>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="main.fileAsyncWrapper">
      <target xsi:type="RetryingWrapper" name="main.fileRetryWrapper" retryCount="10" retryDelayMilliseconds="1000">
          <target
              xsi:type="File"
              name="main.file"
              layout="${message}"
              fileName="${logPath}\win-service-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
              archiveFileName=" ${logPath}\archive\service-main-{#}.log"
              archiveNumbering="Rolling"
              maxArchiveFiles="10"
              encoding="utf-8"
              keepFileOpen="true"
              openFileCacheTimeout="30"/>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="main.fileAsyncWrapper" />
  </rules>
```

Somehow, the old files are not being deleted (I now have 12 of them in my directory). Archive directory isn't even created. What did I do wrong? 
[Per documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target), I removed `archiveEvery="Day"`, it wasn't getting the result I want. But removal didn't get the deletion working.
I run Windows Server with NLog 4.5.5 and .NET 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration doesn't make any sense to me. Think you have to explain how you expect your configuration to work. Any reason why you are not following the examples: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

But because you have configured `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}` in the FileName, and have not specified archiveEvery (or archiveAboveSize) then it will never trigger any archive-operation.

I suggest you configure your NLog like this:

```
      <target
          xsi:type="File"
          name="main.file"
          layout="${message}"
          fileName="${logPath}\service-main.log"
          archiveFileName="${logPath}\archive\service-main-{#}.log"
          archiveNumbering="Rolling"
          archiveEvery="Day"
          maxArchiveFiles="10"
          encoding="utf-8"
          keepFileOpen="true" />
```

Or you configure your NLog like this (Requires NLog 4.5 or newer):

```
      <target
          xsi:type="File"
          name="main.file"
          layout="${message}"
          fileName="${logPath}\win-service-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
          maxArchiveFiles="10"
          encoding="utf-8"
          keepFileOpen="true" />
```

Or you configure NLog like this (Supports NLog 4.4 or older):

```
      <target
          xsi:type="File"
          name="main.file"
          layout="${message}"
          fileName="${logPath}/win-service-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
          archiveFileName="${logPath}/win-service-{#}.log"
          archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
          archiveNumbering="Date"
          archiveEvery="Year"
          maxArchiveFiles="10"
          encoding="utf-8"
          keepFileOpen="true" />
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I think the issue was the configuration was wrong from the start. I did read the docs multiple times, haven't found your link though